# Is it possible to have multiple Chat Bots under one Project on Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, chatbot, dialogflow-es

Recently I ran out of project space building chatbots with DialogFlow. I don't think I am using the best standard with projects on Google Cloud (any tips would be great!) and since I tried creating a new chatbot it would tell me I am out of project space.

Is it possible to put these chatbots under the same project ID? Keeps projects low while being able to still make chatbots?

Thanks

Comment: Unless you are leaving your projects dormant, you can request for an increase in quota for more projects.

Comment: Hey @VikramTiwari, thanks for your comment. I did ask for an increase in the quota alright. Was wondering if I was doing something wrong in relation to filling up unnecessary space in projects. You can set a bot to a project that already exists or create a new one. But thanks a million!

Comment: Best practice would be to keep a bot on one project and scale out projects. Remember that deploying a bot on facebook vs slack can still be done from a single project. So don't partition on those. Rest should be good.

Comment: Ah savage! I couldn't find best standards for bot building but I guess it is kind of just getting traction now. Would standards for clients in bot building be say 1 client 1 project 1 bot?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Only one Dialogflow agent can be created per Google project.  You can request an increase in Google project limits, add billing to your account to increase the limit (you don't have to pay any money, just add a billing account), or delete any unused projects (though this takes a month).

You can also connect an existing Google Cloud project that doesn't have a Dialogflow agent associated with it to a new Dialogflow agent when you're creating a new agent.

Comment: I was able to get the project quota increased without the billing information :). But thanks for your input :). Really helpful!

Comment: Glad to hear!  Please upvote/mark my answer as correct if you found it helpful.