# Multiple AppScript chatbots for a single project

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-hangouts

In our company, we use an AppScript Chatbot to support our collegues in questions related to our area. (We have actually a FAQ that weekly spam on a space with some tips of how to proceed and contact our team)

We wanted to create a 2nd one to support our employees in another matter and I'm wondering if its possible to use the same Google Project to do so or if I have to create a new project.

I've searched the documentation but I really couldn't figure it out.

Comment: What do you mean by "Google Project"? Are you referring to Google Apps Script project or to Google Cloud Project? What have you tried?

Comment: I'm not sure if this applies to you but you can only have one webapp per project but you can have more than one project per spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46826129/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-chat-bots-under-one-project-on-google-cloud) that explains you can only have one Dialogflow agent per Google project. I believe this scenario is similar to yours.